# Issue on delete a file in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to delete a file in laravel 5 application .
My controller code is

```
public function deleteImages(){
        $image = public_path() . '/uploads/images/'.Input::get('image');
        Storage::Delete($image);
    }
```

i'm getting an error message like

```
local.ERROR: exception 'League\Flysystem\FileNotFoundException' with message 'File not found at path: var/www/html/wonders/uploads/images/Copy1Copy1Kuruva-Islands.jpg' in /var/www/html/wonders/vendor/league/flysystem/src/Filesystem.php:381
```

But the file is really existing and the path is correct. But i'm wondering why it shows such an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation I found:

> When using the local driver, note that all file operations are relative to the **root** directory defined in your configuration file. By default, this value is set to the **storage/app** directory. Therefore, the following method would store a file in storage/app/file.txt:

```
Storage::disk('local')->put('file.txt', 'Contents');
```

The way I see it you can't use `Storage::delete` here because you are trying to delete a file in your public folder.

Try one of these that I found on Laravel Recipies:

```
// Delete a single file
\File::delete($filename);

// Delete multiple files
\File::delete($file1, $file2, $file3);

// Delete an array of files
$files = array($file1, $file2);
\File::delete($files);
```

I've added a leading \ because you are using Laravel 5.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the 
File::delete($filename);

Or refer to these link
http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/133/deleting-a-file

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-how-to-delete-a-file-using-filesystem

Comment: $image = public_path() . '/uploads/images/'.Input::get('image');

              if(File::exists($image)){
            File::delete($image);
          }

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your code is correct: have you checked the ownership and permissions of the file you wish to delete? Maybe your web server user does not have the proper permissions to manipulate said file.

I am not sure what platform you are working on, but in a debian / apache2 environment, the file owner should generally be www-data and the permissions should be 644.

Comment: i'm working in ubuntu apache2 environment. All permission is set correct.